# How to reliably test OAuth2 login flow with protractor

Tags: angularjs, testing, oauth-2.0, protractor

I've been playing with protractor for the last few hours, the first test I've written is to test login via oauth2.

The problem is, when testing this manually, browser will remember my credentials after the first time and automatically finish the flow for me(by which I mean I don't have to type in username/password again). To go through the flow again, I typically have to clear browser data first.

I can't figure out how to do this with protractor though. With protractor, after the first time, I still have to send username and password, **but protractor will automatically click login button for me**. So the code below passes, but if I uncomment `submitBtn.click();`, the test will fail with the following error:

```
NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By(css selector, input.btn.btn-primary.btn-block)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:717:27
  at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1379:14)
  at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2913:14)
  at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2896:21)
  at asyncRun (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2775:27)
  at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)Error
  at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:403:27)
  at ElementArrayFinder._this.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:101:30)
  at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as click] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:740:22)
  at public/test/e2e/login_with_github.spec.js:66:27
```

test code:

```
describe('login_with_github', function() {
    it('login with github oauth2', function() {
        browser.get('http://localhost:3001');
        element(by.css('.btn-login-with-github')).click();
        var loginField = element(by.id('login_field'));
        var passwordField = element(by.id('password'));
        var submitBtn = element(by.css('input.btn.btn-primary.btn-block'));
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function(handles) {
                // switch to the newly openned window
                let oldWindowHandle = handles[0];
                let newWindowHandle = handles[1];
                browser.switchTo().window(newWindowHandle).then(function() {
                    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
                    expect(loginField.waitReady()).to.eventually.be.ok;
                    expect(passwordField.waitReady()).to.eventually.be.ok;
                    expect(submitBtn.waitReady()).to.eventually.be.ok;

                    loginField.sendKeys('username@gmail.com');
                    passwordField.sendKeys(password);
                    //submitBtn.click(); // can't do this after the first time.

                    browser.switchTo().window(oldWindowHandle).then(function() {
                        browser.driver.sleep(2000);

                        expect(element(by.css('.foo')).getText()).to.eventually.contain('bar');
                    });
                })
            })
       })
  })
```

I'm looking for a solution which can either mimic the manual test process, or resolve the protractor hanging problem, so that every time I run this spec it will fill in username/password, click signin button, wait for redirect and go back to main page.

Any advice is much appreciated!

**EDIT**

I have tried

```
beforeEach(function() {
    console.log('port:', port);
    browser.get('http://localhost:'+port);

    browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); 
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
})
```

it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: have you tried browser.manage().deleteAllCookies(); to simulate what you did by hand with the history?

Comment: @JeremyKahan, yes, but it has no effect. It looks browser.manage is no longer in protractor 4.0.10's API document.

Comment: I see you are right about the documentation. It is a little gross, but does refresh help?

Comment: @JeremyKahan, unfortunately no, browser.refresh() doesn't make a different either. I think the correct command to delete cookies in 4.0+ is browser.driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(), but again it doesn't fix the problem. I'm not a 'web guy' but still i'm surprised to see this not working. I'd imagine testing oauth end to end is a quite common task...

Comment: submitBtn.click().then(function() { /* passing case do nothing */}, function(err) { /* error handling here, probably do nothing */}) see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/fcd973b8f8b0164bd/docs/faq.md#how-can-i-catch-errors-such-as-elementnotfound

Answer (score 0):

// That is some what i did when i had same issue to run each test independently

```html
afterEach(function () {
       //code to logout 
        // clear all session storage to make run every test independently
        browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
        browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');

    })
```

afterEach(function () {

```
   // code to logout         
    browser.executeScript('window.sessionStorage.clear();');
    browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');

})
```

Comment: I did this in beforeEach, made no difference. It's a bit tricky to do it in afterEach because I no longer have a window open.